# Images in an email is not displaying in IE

Tags: image, internet-explorer, html-email

I have created an HTML email for a client, who then asked me to post it to their server for viewing on the web. It is a basic table layout with images and some links.

Everything appears to work in all major email clients, as well as Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. However, All versions of IE simply do not display the images. You can see the site here.

http://poweredbyprofessionals.com/email/2012-10-MRF/

I verified that the images are RGB and not CMYK, as well as ran it through a validator. Nothing seems to fix the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Replace `width="auto"` and `height="auto"` by the real width and height.

## Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/yrVsL/1/

## Code modified

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center"> 
                <font color="#005697" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:18px; line-height:36px;">
                        <strong> Join Us!! <br/></strong> 
                </font>
                <font color="#008754" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px;">
                    <strong>Wings of Hope for Melanoma</strong><br />
                            a fundraising gala to benefit the <br />
                            Melanoma Research Foundation<br /><br />
                </font>
                <font color="#000" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:20px;">

                    <strong> Thursday, October 11, 2012<br/>
                    6:00 PM to 10:00 PM<br />
                    Gotham Hall <br />
                    1356 Broadway, New York<br /><br />
                    </strong>
                    
                    <strong><a href="http://poweredbyprofessionals.com/melanoma/Purchase.html">Click here for more                                 information, to purchase tickets or make a donation!</a></strong>
                </font>        
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <a href="http://www.poweredbyprofessionals.com/melanoma/Purchase.html" target="_blank">
                    <img style="display: block;" src="http://poweredbyprofessionals.com/email/2012-10-MRF/images/Slice-1.jpg" alt="Slice-1" width="550" height="257" />
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <img style="display: block;" src="http://poweredbyprofessionals.com/email/2012-10-MRF/images/Slice-2.jpg" alt="Slice-2" width="550" height="446" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">    
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img style="display: block;" src="http://poweredbyprofessionals.com/email/2012-10-MRF/images/Slice-4.jpg" alt="Slice-4" width="275" height="99" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="http://www.poweredbyprofessionals.com/melanoma/Purchase.html" target="_blank">
                                    <img style="display: block;" src="http://poweredbyprofessionals.com/email/2012-10-MRF/images/Slice-3.jpg" alt="Slice-3" width="275" height="99" />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>                    
            
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <img style="display: block;" src="http://poweredbyprofessionals.com/email/2012-10-MRF/images/Slice-5.jpg" alt="Slice-5" width="550" height="319" />
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <img style="display: block;" src="http://poweredbyprofessionals.com/email/2012-10-MRF/images/Slice-6.jpg" alt="Slice-2" width="550" height="99" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <a href="http://www.poweredbyprofessionals.com/melanoma/Purchase.html" target="_blank">
                    <img style="display: block;" src="http://poweredbyprofessionals.com/email/2012-10-MRF/images/Slice-7.jpg" alt="Slice-1" width="550" height="99" />
                    </a>
                </td>
            </tr>                        
            
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">    
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="http://www.poweredbyprofessionals.com" target="_blank">
                                    <img style="display: block;" src="http://poweredbyprofessionals.com/email/2012-10-MRF/images/Slice-8.jpg" alt="Slice-3" width="180" height="87" />
                                </a>                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="http://www.melanoma.org" target="_blank">
                                    <img style="display: block;" src="http://poweredbyprofessionals.com/email/2012-10-MRF/images/Slice-9.jpg" alt="Slice-3" width="180" height="87" />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="http://www.stanadler.com" target="_blank">
                                    <img style="display: block;" src="http://poweredbyprofessionals.com/email/2012-10-MRF/images/Slice-10.jpg" alt="Slice-3" width="180" height="87" />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>        
            
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```